# php include path by using .. (double dot) to reference

Tags: php, linux, windows, include, realpath

I got a question regarding, PHP include path, it behaves differently in two environment.

Folder Structure:

**Windows**

```
|-C:\wamp\www\cms\themes\child
|-C:\wamp\www\cms\themes\parent
```

**Linux**

```
|-/var/www/html/cms/themes/child
|-/var/www/html/cms/themes/parent
```

**Linux Environtment**

```
var_dump(realpath('/')); // means /
var_dump(realpath('/../parent/scripts/import.php')); //boolean false
include('/../parent/scripts/import.php'); //it will not work
include('../parent/scripts/import.php'); //it will not work, except it will reference parent folder
```

**Windows Environment**

```
var_dump(realpath('/')); //C:\
var_dump(realpath('/../parent/scripts/import.php')); //boolean false
include('../parent/scripts/import.php'); //am thinking it will work at first, but it does not work in windows (feel weird)
include('/../parent/scripts/import.php'); //it work in windows (feel weird)
```

I know the best practise is, it work in both platform

```
include(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/../parent/scripts/import.php');
```

But I would like to know about this, is it a PHP bug or what cause this?

Comment: Btw, `realpath()` only works on files that exist; i.e. it's not a string operation.

Comment: I can say for sure that `"/../parent/scripts/import.php"` will not work for either environment; did you make a typo?

Comment: Hi Jack, as I mention, the path is correct, I just want to know more why windows works (but not logically). From my understanding is ../ means referencing to the parent folder structure.

Comment: Yes, `../` means parent, but `/../` means parent of root folder (which is the root folder itself).

Comment: Why do you need `realpath` in the first place?

Comment: The reason I ask this because, my development is in Windows, which I had use the `/../`, but when I upload to my live server, it breaks, that why I found out something is not correct. It's make me come and clarify it. Obviously the only answer is windows file system and linux file system.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

no it is not a bug it is for difference between window file system and linux file system